# ggplot and maps: how to bold borders of the regions

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, border, bold

I'm trying to draw map using a shapefile. The shapefile (prov2022) is this

https://easyupload.io/j8bdaf

This is a screenshot of it
[image: SHAPEFILE]

COD_REG = is the code of the regions.

COD_PROV = is the code of the provices.

Here an example of the dataset instead

```
COD_PROV     Province               Real wage 
1            Torino                 1962,18
6            Alessandria            1742,85
5            Asti                   1541,81
96           Biella                 1612,2
4            Cuneo                  1574
3            Novara                 1823,53
103          Verbano -Cusio-Ossola  1584,49
2            Vercelli               1666,21
7            Aosta                  1747,81
10           Genova                 2066,42
8            Imperia                1498,01
11           La Spezia              1871,34
9            Savona                 1770,41
15           Milano                 2240,03
16           Bergamo                1729,17
17           Brescia                1773,38
13           Como                   1832,57
```

I'm drawing the map using this script ( which works perfectly)

```
right_join(prov2022, dataset, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Real wage`)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( "#FFFFFF","#FFFF00", "#FF0000", "#000000"))
```

The map I get is divided inside according with the borders of each province. Is there a way to draw in bold also the geographical boundaries of the regions?? ( each region has inside 6/7 provinces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the shapefile info on each region (i.e. one big geometry that includes all of its provinces), then it's best to create those for each region first in a separate dataframe. Then you can easily plot them as another layer (with a thicker 'linewidth' argument) to get your desired effect. e.g.

```
regions <- prov2022 %>%
  group_by(COD_REG) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))

right_join(prov2022, dataset, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = `Real wage`) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( "#FFFFFF","#FFFF00", "#FF0000", "#000000")) +
  geom_sf(data = regions, aes(geometry = geometry), linewidth = 2, fill = NA)
```

Comment: Hi @Bowhaven and thanks for the answer. It seems it doesn't work. R replies `Error in `geom_sf()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'Real wage' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Ah apologies, I hadn't spotted that your 'fill' aesthetic was in the ggplot call. I've corrected it now :) Sorry that I can't run it to check but you only provided the '.shp' file but "Shapefiles" consist of several files with the same basename that reside in the same directory, only one of them having extension '.shp'.

Comment: thank @Bowhaven. It is the first time I use the shapefiles. Yes, I ve a directory with several files inside and I've open one of them randomly (the .sph one). When I realize that my script works fine with it, I didn't wonder what the others were for... Am I using the wrong one?

Comment: and yes! your script works perfectly!!

Comment: No probs, you're right to use the '.shp' to read the shapefile! I was just saying that I can't open your shapefile because you only uploaded the '.shp' but you need all associated files (e.g. .shx, .cpg, .dbf etc) to be in the same directory to read it in. But no worries now :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll be very useful in case of oher questions